# How to choose provisional profile for the iphone application when you build your application for device

Tags: iphone

Please tell me what is the process of the provisional profile choose in our application when we create device build

Comment: Have you visited the provisioning portal? There are guides there.

Answer (score 0):

The default iPhone Developer profile (under Automatic Profile Selector) is usually the Code Signing Identity to select for a Debug or Release device test build, unless you are testing IAP which requires a non-wildcard App ID.

This assumes you have your certificates and have registered your device UDIDs in the iOS Developer Portal.